# Problems specifying nzmax in sparse command from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I would like to create a sparse matrix of size n × n.
As usual i, j are row and column indices, s are the values.
The command

```
    S=sparse(i,j,s,n,n);
```

works fine, but uses a lot of memory during creation of S. According to the documentation MATLAB uses nzmax=length(s) as default.
To save memory, I want to specify nzmax for S which I can compute in advance.
For testing purpose (I already created S with the above command) I calculate

```
    nonzeros=nzmax(S);
```

and call

```
    S=sparse(i,j,s,n,n,nonzeros);
```

Note that in my example nonzeros is much smaller than length(s). Also, nnz(S)=nzmax(S).
Then I get the error message

> Error using sparse: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Can somebody explain this behavior to me, please? What is a possible remedy/workaround?

Let me add a code snippet as example

```
   i=randi(10,1000,1);
   j=randi(10,1000,1);
   s=rand(1000,1);
   ell=size((unique([i j],'rows')),1);
   S=sparse(i,j,s,10,10,ell);
Error using sparse: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
   S=sparse(i,j,s,10,10);
   nnz(S)
ans = 100
   ell
ell =  100
   nzmax(S)
ans =  100
```

Comment: So, you have duplicate index pairs right? Check out `spalloc`.

Comment: Yes, I have duplicate index pairs. When using spalloc, how can I then efficiently generate matrix S?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `accumarray`, specifying that you're working with sparse matrices (the 6th argument):

```
n = 100;
num = 10000;
i = randi(n,num,1);
j = randi(n,num,1);
s = ones(num, 1);

A = accumarray([i, j], s, [n,n], [], 0, true);
```

This uses the following structure for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
A = accumarray(subs,val,sz,fun,fillval,issparse)
```

An alternative is to use `spalloc` first. That way you should avoid the default initialization.

```
A = spalloc(n, n, non_z);
A(sub2ind(size(A),i,j)) = s;
```

Yet another alternative is to use `unique` with `'rows'` as the second input to count the number of unique index pairs.

```
uni_ind = numel(unique([i,j], 'rows'));
A = sparse(i, j, s, n, n, uni_ind);
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, the accumarray versions works. It seems to be a little bit slower than the sparse version. However, on my computer (16 Gig memory) accumarray needed 44% mem and sparse 30% (according to top command in Linux terminal). I have nnz(S)=27,984,002 and size(S)=4,000,000 x 4,000,000. S needs around 460 MByte only according to whose command in MATLAB.

Comment: Moreover, as written in the question I can calculate nonzeros, which correspond to your uni_ind, but then MATLAB throws the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, because indices (i,j) may appear a few times. I am just wondering why MATLAB throws an error when specifying the correct number of nonzeros.

Comment: Yes. It spikes if I do not specify nzmax because then by default nzmax=length(s) which in my case is about 10 to 20 times larger than necessary. If I specify the presumably correct value it does not work at all.

Comment: Very nice `accumarray` answer.